# The Tau Manifesto

Tags: recreational-mathematics, pi

What really is the Tau Manifesto, and why is a large section of the math community in its favour? Wouldn't it be too much work and effort to edit, and republish the countless texts in mathematics? 
Lastly, what is it (proper mathematical reason) that makes some people prefer Tau over π?

Comment: I would say that most mathematician don't really have an opinion on this matter... It seems to be something that's discussed more in news papers then among working mathematicians

Comment: "why is a large section of the math community in its favour?" [citation needed]. In all seriousness, in my experience, the only people who discuss $\tau$ are a minority in favour of it, but the overwhelming majority just *doesn't care*. This leads to any discussion about $\tau$ seeming like many are in favour; but the group of people discussing it are not representative of the math community on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tau manifesto is a document detailing the reasons why $6.28$ is more natural than $3.14$. I think it's an exaggeration to say that "a large portion" of the math community is in its favour, I would say that most are relatively indifferent. I like the idea, but as you said, it's too much work to really implement the change, and therefore not fasible. If I ever get transported back in time to ancient Greece or something, and get the chance to restart mathematics and science the way I want, this will definitely be one of the changes I make (along with making electrons positively charged and functions postfixed).

I think the main mathematical reason that $\tau$ is seen as more natural is that it relates a circle's radius to its circumference, rather than using the diameter. The diameter is much easier to measure in practice (take a pipe, for instance, how do you measure the radius of that?). However, the circle is *defined* from its radius (try defining a circle by referring to its diameter, and get a definition that isn't also satisfied by the [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle), or just using "half the diameter" instead of the radius). Therefore, it is more natural to also make the fundamental circle constant refer to the radius.

The second argument is that most of the time when $\pi$ appear in mathematical identities, it is there because it represents *half* a revolution. Writing it as $\tau/2$ instead would therefore signify this relationship better. It would probably also make life easier for the poor high schoolers just learning to do trig in radians.